# phpMyAdmin Warning happens every time

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently I installed apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin on my Ubuntu 18.04 pc.
Every time when I logged and select a table, I get huge warning message in red like this.

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'quill_example',
string 'Asset',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `Asset`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'quill_example',
string 'Asset',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `Asset`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Even I didn't execute a query, but every time I got this message and after few clicks, browser get stuck. After that I restart apache, mysql services.
I need to solve the problem.